# Remove single character in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, sentiment-analysis

i'm working on sentiment analysis with Arabic language by using R and in cleaning step i need to remove the single character. 
I used this code to remove them and it works but a had some problem

for example here is the data

```
R<-("للمدافعين قال شركة وطنية قلت أقنعهم يعاملوننا كمواطنينقال جودتها عالية قلت جيدة غيرها غ")
```

as you see here "غ" is single character

```
gsub(" *\\b[[:alpha:]]{1}\\b *", "", R)
[1] "للمدافعين قال شركة وطنية قلت أقنعهم يعاملوننا كمواطنينقال جودتها عالية قلت جيدة غيرها\n"
```

but when I tried to apply it on the whole data set on text column like here

```
subdata1$text = gsub("*\\b[[:alpha:]]{1}\\b *", "", subdata1$text)
```

its doesn't remove anything and I don't known why?

hope you understand me

thank you

Comment: Try `gsub("(*UCP)\\b\\p{L}\\b", "", R, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: yes it is worked thank youuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `[:alpha:]` POSIX character class does not work with all Unicode letters in your case.

I suggest using a PCRE pattern:

```
gsub("(*UCP)\\b\\p{L}\\b", "", R, perl=TRUE)
```

Here, `(*UCP)` is required to make `\b` word boundary Unicode aware and `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter from a BMP plane. The `perl=TRUE` argument is required for the pattern to be processed with the PCRE regex engine.